# Finding time difference in seconds in same table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table something like below.

```
Transaction_ID      step_id       datetime                          City
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc                   2a          14-JUL-18 13:33:03.48783          London
abc                   2b          14-JUL-18 13:33:06.48786          London
abc                   2c          14-JUL-18 13:33:06.48786          London
def                   2a          14-JUL-18 13:34:20.48786          London
def                   2b          14-JUL-18 13:34:22.48786          London
def                   2c          14-JUL-18 13:34:22.48786          London
```

I like to get the time difference in step_id 2a and 2b by grouping transaction_id. I have formed query something like below. but it is working only for specific transaction id. I like to list for all the transaction id.

Please help me in this.

```
SELECT
    c.Transaction_ID,
    (C1.datetime - (
                    SELECT
                        datetime 
                    FROM
                        myTable
                    WHERE 
                        Transaction_ID = 'abc'
                        AND step_id = '2b'
                    )) AS TIMEDIFFERNCE
FROM
    myTable c 
    INNER JOIN myTable C1 ON c.TRANSACTION_ID = C1.TRANSACTION_ID 
                                AND c.step_id = C1.step_id
WHERE
    c.City = 'London'
    AND c.datetime >=  '14-JUL-18 10:58:01' 
    AND c.datetime  <=  '15-JUL-18 00:00:01'
    AND c.Transaction_ID = 'abc'
    AND c.step_id ='2a'
ORDER BY
    c.datetime desc;
```

Expected result is

```
Transaction_ID     timediffInseconds 
------------------------------------
abc                   3
def                   2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT t2a.Transaction_ID,
      (t2b.datetime - t2a.datetime)*(24*60*60) AS diff_in_secs
FROM myTable t2a INNER JOIN
     myTable t2b
     ON t2b.TRANSACTION_ID = t2a.TRANSACTION_ID AND
WHERE t2b.step_id = '2b' AND
      t2a.step_id = '2a' AND
      t2a.City = 'London' AND
      t2a.datetime >=  '14-JUL-18 10:58:01' AND 
      t2a.datetime  <=  '15-JUL-18 00:00:01' AND
ORDER BY c.datetime desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query below:

```
SELECT
    Transaction_ID, 
    (MAX(datetime) - MIN(datetime))*(24*60*60) AS timediffInseconds
FROM
    myTable
WHERE
    step_id IN ('2a', '2b')
    AND City = 'London'
    AND datetime BETWEEN '2018-07-14 10:58:01' AND '2018-07-15 00:00:01'
GROUP BY
    Transaction_ID
HAVING
    MIN(step_id) = '2a'
    AND MAX(step_id) = '2b'
```